# Помогите исправить и объяснить лексические ошибки (указать какая норма нарушена).

Tags: лексика

Пушкин сказал царю, что восстал бы, если бы был в Петербурге, но он был, к сожалению, в отъезде.

Comment: Школьное задание?

Answer (score 1):

Неверное понимание лексического значения слова восстал. Восстал -1.поднялся на борьбу, поднял восстание. Нужно было сказать "принял бы участие в восстании".

Comment: А у меня почему-то сразу возникла ассоциация "восстал из мертвых"

Comment: Да нет, это когда шло следствие по делу декабристов, а среди них были все друзья Пушкина, царь его спросил, почему же его не было на Сенатской площади , почему не принимал участия в восстании.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с Людмилой. "Пушкин сказал царю, что принял бы участие в восстании", если бы был в Петербурге, но он был, к сожалению, в отъезде". Пушкин был не в отъезде, а в ссылке...
По распоряжению царя Пушкин А. С. был выслан в Михайловское, куда и прибыл 9 августа 1824 г. Он жил и творил в Михайловском с 1824 по 1826 год. В сентябре 1926 года Николай I приказал доставить Пушкина в Москву, куда Николай I прибыл на коронацию.
Так кончились годы изгнания Пушкина. Прямо с дороги, измученный, грязный, предстал  он перед царем и на вопрос царя, принял ли бы он участие в декабрьском восстании 1825 года, прямо и с гордостью отвечал: «Непременно, государь! Все друзья мои были в заговоре, и, будь я в Петербурге, я был бы с ними».
Я думаю, это речевая ошибка в лексической сочетаемости: "Пушкин сказал царю, что восстал бы, если бы был..." Кто восстал бы? Пушкин или царь? И опять же кто был бы? Пушкин или царь?